# Symfony2 - Able to add data of multiple entities to database but no foreign keys are added

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, persistence

I got 2 tables connected with a foreign key (user_id is in the table persons). I'm able to add data to both of the tables by executing 1 form.
but on the execute i expected that the foreign key would automatically be generated in the table persons.

Here are my enities

#### USERS

```php
namespace Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{

    //Vanaf hier bijgevoegd
    protected $adress;
    protected $person;
    //Einde zelf toegevoegde properties

    /**
     * @var integer $userId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var string $user 
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_password", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userPassword;

    /**
     * @var string $userEmail
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_email", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userEmail;

    /**
     * @var string $userImage
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_image", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userImage;

    /**
     * @var string $userQuestion
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_question", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userQuestion;

    /**
     * @var string $userAnswer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_answer", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userAnswer;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $userCreateddate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_createddate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set userPassword
     *
     * @param string $userPassword
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserPassword($userPassword)
    {
        $this->userPassword = $userPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userPassword
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserPassword()
    {
        return $this->userPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Set userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userEmail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserEmail()
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set userImage
     *
     * @param string $userImage
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserImage($userImage)
    {
        $this->userImage = $userImage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userImage
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserImage()
    {
        return $this->userImage;
    }

    /**
     * Set userQuestion
     *
     * @param string $userQuestion
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserQuestion($userQuestion)
    {
        $this->userQuestion = $userQuestion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userQuestion
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserQuestion()
    {
        return $this->userQuestion;
    }

    /**
     * Set userAnswer
     *
     * @param string $userAnswer
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserAnswer($userAnswer)
    {
        $this->userAnswer = $userAnswer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userAnswer
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserAnswer()
    {
        return $this->userAnswer;
    }

    //Zelf toegevoegde getters & setters

     public function getPerson()
    {
        return $this->person;
    }

    public function setPerson(Persons $person = null)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
    }   

    public function getAdress()
    {
        return $this->adress;
    }

    public function setAdress(Adresses $adress = null)
    {
        $this->adress = $adress;
    }  
}
```

#### PERSONS

```php
namespace Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Persons
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="persons")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Persons
{
    /**
     * @var integer $personId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="person_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $personId;

    /**
     * @var integer $adressId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adress_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $adressId;

    /**
     * @var string $personFamilyname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="person_familyname", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $personFamilyname;

    /**
     * @var string $personFirstname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="person_firstname", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $personFirstname;

    /**
     * @var boolean $personGender
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="person_gender", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $personGender;

    /**
     * @var string $personNationality
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="person_nationality", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $personNationality;

    /**
     * @var Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Get personId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPersonId()
    {
        return $this->personId;
    }

    /**
     * Set adressId
     *
     * @param integer $adressId
     * @return Persons
     */
    public function setAdressId($adressId)
    {
        $this->adressId = $adressId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adressId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAdressId()
    {
        return $this->adressId;
    }

    /**
     * Set personFamilyname
     *
     * @param string $personFamilyname
     * @return Persons
     */
    public function setPersonFamilyname($personFamilyname)
    {
        $this->personFamilyname = $personFamilyname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personFamilyname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPersonFamilyname()
    {
        return $this->personFamilyname;
    }

    /**
     * Set personFirstname
     *
     * @param string $personFirstname
     * @return Persons
     */
    public function setPersonFirstname($personFirstname)
    {
        $this->personFirstname = $personFirstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personFirstname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPersonFirstname()
    {
        return $this->personFirstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set personGender
     *
     * @param boolean $personGender
     * @return Persons
     */
    public function setPersonGender($personGender)
    {
        $this->personGender = $personGender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personGender
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getPersonGender()
    {
        return $this->personGender;
    }

    /**
     * Set personNationality
     *
     * @param string $personNationality
     * @return Persons
     */
    public function setPersonNationality($personNationality)
    {
        $this->personNationality = $personNationality;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personNationality
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPersonNationality()
    {
        return $this->personNationality;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Persons
     */
    public function setUser(\Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

#### CONTROLLER

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
    $user = new Users();
    $person = new Persons();
    //$adress = new Adresses();

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if($form->isValid()){
                $person = $form->getData();
                //$adress = $form->getData();

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->persist($user->getPerson());
                //$em->persist($user->getAdress());


                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('indexpage'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('GeoCityTroopersBundle:User:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
}
```

#### USERTYPE

```php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder->add('person', new PersonType());
        $builder->add('userEmail');
        $builder->add('userPassword', 'password');
        $builder->add('userImage');
        $builder->add('userQuestion');
        $builder->add('userAnswer');
        //$builder->add('adress', new AdressType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

#### PERSONTYPE

```php
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('personFamilyname');
        $builder->add('personFirstname');
        $builder->add('personNationality');
        $builder->add('personGender');
        //$builder->add('adressId');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Persons',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person';
    }
}
```

I have tried to add in the annotations of Users the following:

```
/**
* Bidirectional (INVERSE SIDE)
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Persons",cascade={"persist"})
*
*/
```

But this didn't worked either.
I have a feeling there is something wrong with the setup of my database, the relation between persons and users is one to one.

update: Deleted unnecessary

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have posted a lot of code, maybe before each chunk you could sum it up, and if there is something that is not important you could remove it

Comment: Inside the user entity you didn't map person so it isn't saved by Doctrine. If you do something like this and then persist both: `$person = $user->getPerson();` followed by `$person->setUser($user);` it should work.

Comment: First thanks for the responses,but i'm new to symfony and the whole mapping... What code is needed to map the person inside the user?
I assumed "getPerson()" and "setPerson()" was enough... Thx

Comment: There are several problems with the mapping, and you can improve in your database setup. For mental sanity, and to conform to Doctrine standard, all primary keys should be named 'id' (create an entity with php app/console doctrine:generate:entity and you'll find out)

Comment: I still don't understand your use case. Do you want a web page showing user info along as the info for one or more related persons?